# Saved Searches and Alerting in Coveo

Tags: coveo

I'm looking at Coveo capability for a project and the documentation isn't clear in the area of alerting (high level docs are marketing let, and low level docs are mainly API based without a lot of explanation). I see you can set up a 'subscription' to alert on, but it's not clear exactly what that subscription can be against.

Essentially I'm trying to find out if you can save a search query/criteria, and then alert if a document matching that query/criteria is indexed. Essentially what you can do with Percolators in Elastic (if you are familiar with that).

Is this possible in Coveo?

Any pointers to precise and clear documentation that I'm missing would be appreciated.

Comment: I've found more comprehensive documentation and I don't think Coveo provides this type of feature. Hoping someone can correct me there :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a feature that Coveo provides, especially not for end users.
The only way to design something like you're asking would be to create your own code that queries Coveo, say every day, with a specific query that normally returns no result, and checks if results are returned. When results are returned, the system would then be able to alert you.
If you think Coveo should create that feature, please feel welcome to post it on the Coveo Ideas portal: https://connect.coveo.com/s/ideas